# Как менять раскладку в Python? Тоесть "Привет" становится "Ghbdtn"

Tags: python

Как менять раскладку в Python? То есть в моей переменной есть строка "привет", и мне нужно поменять её на "ghbdtn".

Answer (score 5):

Составляете ассоциации и заменяете, например через [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
def from_ghbdtn(text):
    layout = dict(zip(map(ord, '''qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,./`QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:"ZXCVBNM<>?~'''),
                               '''йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю.ёЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ,Ё'''))

    return text.translate(layout)

text = 'B ,skb ghj,ktvs c ujcntdjq dhjlt ,s? gjcvjnhb '
print(from_ghbdtn(text))
```

Comment: так просто, отличное решений

Answer (score 2):

Создать словарь, в котором ключами будут буквы английского алфавита, а значениями - русского. Перебрать посимвольно строку и заменить все символы.

```py
translator = {
    'a': 'ф',
    'b': 'и',
    'c': 'c'
    # и так далее
}

word = 'something'
translated_word = ''.join([translator[x] for x in word])
```

Ну, это в базовом виде. Хорошо было бы еще учесть, что кроме букв там могут быть и другие символы, например. Тогда можно сделать как-нибудь так

```
translated_word = ''.join([translator.get(x) or x for x in word])
```

Answer (score 0):

ну можно так

```
def translit(text):
    cyrillic = 'привет'

    latin = 'g.h.b.d.t.n'.split('.') # таблица транслитерации 
    trantab = {k:v for k,v in zip(cyrillic,latin)}
    newtext = ''
    for ch in text:
        casefunc =  str.capitalize if ch.isupper() else str.lower
        newtext += casefunc(trantab.get(ch.lower(),ch))
    return newtext

print(translit('привет'))
```

в переменную `cyrillic` записать все русские буквы, а в `latin` их английские